# How to retrieve id from URL with Cakephp?

Tags: cakephp

I have posts controller and I can route to each post via their id.

Is there any way to fetch the id from the URL for storing that id in `Comments` table `post_id` foreign key field?

If yes, can I have a hint or a little help?

Answer (score 0):

assuming CakePHP 2.0 and the URL: `APP/posts/view/1`, in your `view.ctp`

you can access all the information from the URL using `debug($this->request->url);`

based on information provided you want `pass`, so:

```
$post_id = $this->request->url['pass'][0];
```

pass this value to a hidden field in a form with the action for `add` in the `CommentsController`

```
echo $this->Form->input('post_id', array('type'=>'hidden', 'value'=>$post_id));
```

When you submit the form, there will be an array key `data[Comment][post_id] // 1`

which will then populate the `comments` table with the correct `post_id` foreign key.

Comment: Just put an argument to the view method. `public function view($id) {}` so `/posts/views/1` -> `$id = 1`

Comment: @tigrang - turn this into an answer. Ross answered OP literally, but your way is far more correct/canonical.

Comment: I agree; but OP was suggesting how to add the `post_id` to a `Comments` table, so as a result using the value in a hidden input would probably be more conventional. I also have the suspicion this person has created a new account and asked the same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12915119/cakephp-unable-to-insert-foreign-key) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12881351/cakephp-retrieving-a-specific-field), given the `userscomments` code is identical. He is trying to create a form to add comments to a given record; which I have provided suitable information for.